# How to selectively disable articles or discussions in Salesforce communities Napili template based on topic

Tags: community, napili, topics, data-category

My topics are organized either by Forum or Knowledge Base
Under Knowledge base topic I am using Data Categories which are assigned to Knowledge articles.  Under Forums I will have topics and they will only be used for discussions.  The issue I have is the Napili lightning component always shows both discussions and articles for each topic and there is no way to remove one or the other based on the topic being a data category or a topic.  I tried to this via custom CSS but it blocks either one.  Can I put some logic into the CSS to make this work?